# What is CocoaPods "(unused)"

Tags: ios, cocoapods

After running `pod outdated`, I get the following output

```
Updating spec repo `master`
Analyzing dependencies
The following pod updates are available:
- AFNetworking 2.4.4 -> 2.5.4 (latest version 3.0.0-beta.2)
- HexColors 2.2.1 -> 2.2.1 (latest version 3.0.0)
- Overcoat 3.0.0 -> (unused) (latest version 3.2.1)
- ReactiveCocoa 2.5 -> 2.5 (latest version 4.0.4-alpha-4)
```

I have not seen this "unused" term before

**i.e.**

`Overcoat 3.0.0 ->`**(unused)** `(latest version 3.2.1)`

What is this? And what does it mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After analyzing the source code, I think that `(unused)` means that the Pod is not in your Podfile (probably you removed it and didn't reinstall)

```
AFNetworking     2.4.4    ->      2.5.4            (latest version 3.0.0-beta.2)
    ^              ^                ^                             ^
Pod name     Installed version   Podfile version                Latest
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/691e3de4405a0b7174ccd9ca85912a045d286aa2/lib/cocoapods/command/outdated.rb#L60) which inserts this tag, which looks like this:

```
if source_version > lockfile_version
  matching_spec = unlocked_pods.find { |s| s.name == pod_name }
  matching_version =
    matching_spec ? matching_spec.version : '(unused)'
  [pod_name, lockfile_version, matching_version, source_version]
end
```

It appears that this simply means that CocoaPods could not find that Pod within your 'unlocked pods'.

I don't speak Ruby well enough to determine exactly what an "unlocked" pod is (nor am I familiar enough with CocoaPods to have heard the term necessarily... but I am aware of a 'lockfile', and maybe this is related), but [here is the source code for determining that](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/691e3de4405a0b7174ccd9ca85912a045d286aa2/lib/cocoapods/command/outdated.rb#L70):

```
def unlocked_pods
  @unlocked_pods ||= begin
    pods = []
    UI.titled_section('Analyzing dependencies') do
      pods = Installer::Analyzer.new(config.sandbox, config.podfile).
        analyze(false).
        specs_by_target.values.flatten.uniq
    end
    pods
  end
end
```

Comment: I am trying to analyze that too. I can read ruby but understanding their undocumented code is almost impossible.

Comment: Unlocked pods meaning those that don't have a version specified in your `Podfile` or any of the inherited `Podfile`s.